# Please explain about Hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm not clear about Hyperledger. Please help!

1. What is Hyperledger?
2. What is Hyperledger Composer?
3. What is Hyperledger Fabric?
4. What is Hyperledger Fabric SDK GO?
5. What is consensus algorithm use in Hyperledger?
6. And Hyperledger have a miner or not?

Comment: `Hyperledger` is designed according to `MICS` principle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Ans 1:** Hyperledger is not: Not a company. Not a cryptocurrency. Not a blockchain. Hyperledger is rather something like a hub for open industrial blockchain development.
Further explanation you can follow this: https://blockgeeks.com/guides/what-is-hyperledger/

**Ans 2:** **Hyperledger Composer** is a set of collaboration tools for building blockchain business networks that make it simple and fast for business owners and developers to create smart contracts and blockchain applications to solve business problems.
Further explanation: https://www.hyperledger.org/projects/composer

**Ans 3:** Hyperledger Fabric is a business blockchain framework hosted by the Linux Foundation intended as a foundation for developing blockchain applications or solutions with a modular architecture. Hyperledger Fabric allows components such as consensus and membership services to be plug-and-play.

Further explanation: https://www.ibm.com/blockchain/hyperledger.html and https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/

**Ans 4:** See this to know better about Fabric SDK GO: https://wiki.hyperledger.org/projects/fabric-sdk-go

**Ans 5:** See this to know better about consensus algorithm. https://www.hyperledger.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Hyperledger_Arch_WG_Paper_1_Consensus.pdf

**Ans 6:** No miner needed in Hyperledger. Ordering service done this.

Answer (score 1):

Also the primary difference between Hyperledger and other Blockchain networks such as Ethereum is that it is permissioned and it targets enterprise use cases, which operate on a certain degree of trust (partial trust) under a governance model dictated by the underlying consortium. Since the participants are not completely anonymous, the need of having a full BFT consensus implementation such as PoW can be eliminated. This in turn improves the network performance as well as makes it more scalable.

Answer (score 1):

**What is hyperledger ?**

It is neither crypto currency nor a blockchain network or a a company .it’s kinda open source initiative hosted by Linux foundation supported by global leaders such as intel and IBM to advance blockchain technologies.

**What is hyperldger fabric?**

Hyperldeger has lot of umbrella projects under it .hyperledger fabric is one such project led by IBM .

Hypeldger fabric provides a platform to develop high scale blockchain applications with flexible amount of permissions .hyperledger universe has 4 other frameworks namely Iroha, Sawtooth, Indy, and Burrow.

**what is hyperledger composer ?**

hyperledger fabric is a hyperledger framework while composer is a hyperledger module.I suggest you start with hyperledger composer since it offers many benefits such as

Faster creation of blockchain apps, eliminating the big effort required to build blockchain applications from scratch
it is well-tested therefore less risk involved, easier to understand and align with different domains
Greater flexibility as the higher-level abstractions make it far simpler to iterate.
further hyperledger composer is written in javascript.Composer provides you a bunch of easy-to-use components that you can quickly learn and implement.

hyperledger fabric takes you a layer lower. if you wanna start learning about blockchain architecture and underlying processes go ahead with fabric.

**What is consensus algorithm use in Hyperledger?** 
consensus mechanism in hyperledger is called "proof of authority"

**And Hyperledger have a miner or not?** 
hyperledger does not have miners or any mining. mining is necessary when consensus mechanism of the network is "proof of work" .in hyperledger consensus mechanism is "proof of authority"

**checkout my article** .everything you have asked is explained in detail here 
https://medium.com/@fnote/curious-case-of-hyperledger-fabric-ce0292906187

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger is an umbrella organization under The Linux Foundation that supports multiple blockchain technologies.  See the chart here: https://www.hyperledger.org/

All Hyperledger projects are open source under the Apache 2 license, although many were originally developed by a contributing organization.

- Hyperledger Burrow implements an Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM)
- Hyperledger Sawtooth is Intel's blockchain technology (and includes an EVM using Hyperledger Burrow
- Hyperledger Fabric is IBM's blockchain technology (explained above)
- Hyperledger Indy is a blockchain specifically focused on identity
- Hyperleder Iroha is a blockchain focused on Mobile apps and is developed in Japan
- Hyperledger Besu is an open source Ethereum client